# How to Specify the Target App when setting up PredictionIO for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, predictionio

I'm new to PredictionIO, and I'm following this tutorial http://docs.prediction.io/0.8.0/tutorials/engines/itemrec/rails.html. I got to the step where I need to import a rake task. Well, that doesn't work and I get this error:

```
PredictionIO::EventClient::NotCreatedError: The requested resource could not be found.
```

That happens when I try this line:

```
client.set_user(user.id)
```

Now, right before this step, it says to change file **params/datasource.json** and to **specify the target app**. I don't know how to get this **ID** and I suspect this might be the problem here.

Hope this is clear and someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select a unique number for your application,say **5**.

1. Replace    PIO_APP_ID    with **5** in the rails code and run.This is to inform the event server that incoming events are pertaining to appId=**5**.
2. Once all the events are registered, go to  io.prediction.engines.itemrec/params/datasource.json and change appId to **5**.Now train,deploy the engine in that order.

You can view the events registered by the event server by 
   `curl -i -X GET http://localhost:7070/events.json?appId=5`